# How do I use 'grass7:v.net.spanningtree' from the QGIS python console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-python-console

Assume there are map layers named `filtered_edges` and `points`. I have written the following in the QGIS python console:

```
import processing


fe = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('filtered_edges')[0]
points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')[0]

params = {}
params['input'] = fe
params['points'] = points
params['threshold'] = 350.0
params['output'] = 'memory:spanningtree'


result = processing.run('grass7:v.net.spanningtree', params)

#this is a string, I am expecting a QGSVectorLayer
print(type(result['output']))

#error here
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['output'])

#print(processing.algorithmHelp("grass7:v.net.spanningtree"))
```

It is giving me an error saying result['output'] is a string.

Comment: @user2856 thanks, although this also did not work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a memory layer output, I set the output parameter as a shapefile:

`params['output'] =  'H:/Scripts/TestData/Output/spanningtree.shp'`

Then after running the processing algorithm, I created a QgsVectorLayer using the shapefile output from the algorithm. I then loaded this layer into the map.

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer('H:/Scripts/TestData/Output/spanningtree.shp', "spanningtree", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

It's not quite what I was looking for - I was hoping to be able to directly use a memory layer in the algorithm, but it will suffice for now.